# Handle Success from AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to handle a successful call from the submit below and reload the current page.
How can i best achieve this?

```
$('#modal-confirm').click(function() {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
    $(form).resetForm();
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Comment: If you want it to reload the current page, why are you handlign it with ajax rather than doing a normal form post/get and redirecting on the action page?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass option to `ajaxSubmit()`

```
$(form).ajaxSubmit({
   success:function(){
     alert("complete");
     // do other stuff
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try this out..

```
$('#modal-confirm').on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url     : '...'
  }).done(function(data) {
  //handle your conditions here once the request is successful.  if conditions are met, then...
    location.reload(true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() { // http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/
     location.realod();
    })
    $('#modal-confirm').click(function() {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
        $(form).resetForm();
        $('#myModalOne').modal('toggle');
    });
```